# ViewPager in Constraint Layout with tabbed activity getting cut at bottom for recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I am creating a tabbed layout with ViewPager but instead of using coordinator layout and AppBar, I am using constraint layout. I have a custom title bar, a card, a custom tablayout and a viewpager. The viewpager is holding two fragments and each fragment has a recyclerview. But the data of the recyclerview is cut for last few rows. Can someone please help me understand what is going wrong

This is my main activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Activities.Products">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/MyAppBar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"/>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_total"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/color_primary_text"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Total Balance"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_total">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        style="@style/Widget.App.TabLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_background"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabRippleColor="@null" />
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">

    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus_blue"
    app:tint="@color/color_primary"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can note I have put my viewpager and tabbed layout inside a linearlayout

This is my fragment layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_receivable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Total Receivable: "
    android:textColor="@color/color_primary_text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.craftec.managed.RupeeTextView
    android:id="@+id/amount_receivable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/color_primary_text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text_receivable"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/customer_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:itemCount="10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/amount_receivable"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_customers" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can someone please help me understand what wrong I am doing here. I have been stuck here for a day now. Please help

[image: Blueprint in Andorid Studio od main activity]

Comment: `But the data of the recyclerview is cut for last few rows`. Could you add a picture, to show your problem exactly?

Comment: I have added the blueprint and you can see how viewpager is extended out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your activity layout to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activities.Products">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/MyAppBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_total"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/color_primary_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Total Balance"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        style="@style/Widget.App.TabLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_total"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabRippleColor="@null" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabs" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus_blue"
        app:tint="@color/color_primary" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Update**

What does `android:layout_height="0dp"` or `android:layout_width="0dp"` mean?

In `ConstraintLayout` 0dp is set for - whole empty space.

In case, the view is know where to start and end (`constraintTop_...` and `constraintBottom_...` are set), with 0dp it takes the whole space that display has.
For example, we have views that takes 20% of view, then `RecyclerView` or some other view with `android:layout_width="0dp"` would take 80% of display view

If there would be 2 views, each with `layout_width="0dp"`, then they would take each 50% of free space.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your edit, the viewpager is now within the screen but the recycler view is still going out of screen, I have added text views in fragment layout at top. If I am removing them then the recycler view is coming full

Comment: @HarshPalit , set the `android:layout_height="0dp"` for RecyclerView. With that your `RecyclerVew` should be completelly visible

Comment: Wow it worked for me! You are genius! But can you please help me understand the reason behind it

Comment: @HarshPalit , i have edit my answer. I hope it explains good how it works

Comment: Yes the 0dp height on the view you need to fill the layout did the trick for me sir!